# Taxi facilities in Coimbatore, Indian airport

Tags: airport-transfer, south-india

I would be travelling to the city of Coimbatore in South India and I would like to know if there will be taxi facilities from the Airport to the Hotel. I checked up in Google Maps and I see that the airport is quite a bit away from the city center. So, does anybody know if they have this option of "pre-paid taxis" which is common in some other Indian airports which I have already visited. I would be arriving at around 07:30.

And how expensive would these taxi services be? If they are too expensive, are there any alternate options?

Summoning an Uber is out of question because I do not have an Indian sim card and I cannot use my German number in India as well.

Comment: Have you tried on the airport website? Contacted your hotel to arrange transport?

Comment: I am not sure if there is an official airport website for this airport. By what i read it looks really small with just a few regional aircrafts. As for the hotel transport, I think that is a good idea. Let me try them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering from Coimbatore, hope this answer is helpful for others who travel to Coimbatore Airport.

The airport is **16Km** from the City Center, **Pre-paid taxis are available** as in other Indian airports. You can reach any point of the city from the airport well under **USD 7.5** (INR 500).

Apart from the airport taxi, you can also make use of private taxis that ply over the city. **The maximum cost for a Km is USD 0.3**.

Some of the private taxi networks in Coimbatore are:

- [Taxt Taxi](http://www.taxitaxi.co.in/)
- [RedTaxi](http://redtaxi.co.in/)
- [FastTrack](http://www.fasttrackcalltaxi.in/login.aspx)

Apart from these, app based taxis are also available

- Uber
- Ola

As an alternate, public transport buses are available very frequently. But you are required to **walk** for around **500 metres for the nearest bus stop**. For details on bus routes, you can check the site [way2cbe](http://www.way2cbe.com) (Stopname: SITRA/Airport)

Comment: +1. I think this is the most complete answer that I wanted. For these pre-paid taxis, do I have to pay the complete amount before boarding the taxi? And these pre-paid taxi counters located within the airport building itself?

Comment: @Müller, the pre-paid taxi counter is available just outside the arrival terminal and within the airport complex. You need to pay the full amount based on the approximate range (like 5Km, 10Km), any extra distance to it can be paid at the end of your trip.

Answer (score 6):

According to Rome 2 Rio, the taxi would only cost you few $ (less than 10) to get from the airport to the city center.

Then if you google "Coimbatore airport taxi", you'll find a lot of companies where you can book a taxi in advance :)

Adding some links (I haven't tested any of these companies) :
http://www.savaari.com/coimbatore/airport-taxi

https://www.coimbatoretaxi.com/

http://redtaxi.co.in/

https://www.taxiforsure.com/coimbatore-cabs/airport-service/

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 Yeah it does provide some information but I am not sure if these services are sort of authorized. I have been to a few Indian airports and sometimes whatever I booked earlier through e-mail or through Google links did not really work out. So, I was hoping I could get some local person's information on this if possible.